# multi cultures for specific one area in multi area project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, area, culture

I have a project and this has multi areas
I want to apply culture in just one area. I use culture but this has side effects on another area do you have any idea for solve problem

for example: double in ajax requests converted to a string
changed money type in another area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the culture manually on request based on the route of the specific area:

```cs
public class CustomRouteDataRequestCultureProvider : RequestCultureProvider
{
    public int IndexOfCulture;

    public override Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContext));

        ProviderCultureResult providerResultCulture;

        if (httpContext.Request.Path.Value.Contains("your-area-path"))
            providerResultCulture = new ProviderCultureResult("en");
        else
            providerResultCulture = new ProviderCultureResult("fa");

        return Task.FromResult(providerResultCulture);
    }
}
```

And in Startup class:

```cs
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new CultureInfo[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("fa"),
        new CultureInfo("en")
    };

    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("fa");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

    options.RequestCultureProviders = new[] { new CustomRouteDataRequestCultureProvider { IndexOfCulture = 0 } };
});
```